# WPF Binding TextBox Text Property to a specific ViewModel's Property in a TreeView

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a TreeView which I have bound to a ViewModel called `RootViewModel` which has a collection of ViewModels `ChildViewModel` which has a collection of ViewModels `GrandhChildViewModel`.

I have a text box next to the tree view.

I want to bind the text box's text to a specific property of the selected item **only** when a `GrandChildViewModel` is selected in the tree.  If a `GrandChildViewModel` is not selected, I want the text in the textbox to be empty.  I'd also like to have it so if I change the text in the TextBox when a GrandChild is selected it will update the text for that item in the treeview.  (I'm assuming 2 way binding between the viewmodel<->textbox and viewmodel<->treeview

```
|------------------|
| - Root           |
|   - Child        |     |---------------------------------|
|     - GrandChild |     | Selected GrandChild's Property  |
|     - GrandChild |     |---------------------------------|
|     - GrandChild |                            ^
|   - Child        |                            |
|     - GrandChild |<----- Selected GrandChild -|
|                  |
|------------------|
```

Sample ViewModels:

```
public class RootViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> Children{ get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected{ get { /* code */ } set { /* code */ OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected"); }
}
public class ChildViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<GrandChildViewModel> GrandChildren{ get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected{ get { /* code */ } set { /* code */ OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected"); }
    public string SomeProperty{ get { /* code */ } set { /* code */ OnPropertyChanged("SomeProperty"); }
}
public class GrandChildViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool IsSelected{ get { /* code */ } set { /* code */ OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected"); }
    public bool SomeOtherProperty{ get { /* code */ } set { /* code */ OnPropertyChanged("SomeOtherProperty"); }
}
```

My attempt's so far in Xaml:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                         <Binding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}" ElementName="myTreeView" Path="SelectedItem" Mode="TwoWay" />
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=SomeOtherProperty}" />
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Also tried

```
<TextBox Text={Binding ElementName=myTreeView, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Many Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I found that this is throwing an exception because TwoWay DataBinding on SelectedItem is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this post](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/posts/details/2326) I was able to get this to work.  I set the StackPanel around the text box to bind to the selected item, then bound the text box to the property I care about.

```
<StackPanel DataContext={Binding ElementName=myTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}">
    <TextBox Text={Binding Path=SomeOtherProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Works like a charm.